# Google map with custom image

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Can you help me please implement the google map with custom image pointer?
I found this sample of code at the [google devev site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple)
I have copied it to the page but map is not visible. Can you tell me why?

```js
function initializeMap() {

  var newark = new google.maps.LatLng(40.740, -74.18);
  var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(40.712216, -74.22655),
      new google.maps.LatLng(40.773941, -74.12544));

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: newark
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
      imageBounds);
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

```css
.row {
 height:300px;
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&test=.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid oH">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 w100P" id="map-canvas">
   <div id="mapa"></div>
   <div id="map_bg"> </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2x5kfeb/)

Comment: Why arent u using any reference to the google maps api??

Comment: Please ensure that you add the relevant code in your question, that way the question will still be of use even if the links expire.

Comment: Souce was added to resources but something was wrong. I am sorry. Thank you for the update.

Comment: Your map doesn't have a size ([working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2x5kfeb/2/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is not visible because you have not set css for map-canvas

```
#map-canvas {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
}
```

and no map api also see here i have added this 
https://jsfiddle.net/L2x5kfeb/1/